# Mathematics of genealogical trees

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, trees

I really searched a lot but did not find anything meeting my needs: A place where questions of  [genealogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genealogy), especially the structural and combinatorial analysis of genealogical "trees" of descendants and ancestors of (human) individuals or populations are treated rigorously and mathematically, especially quantitatively.

Genealogical "trees" - in either direction: [family trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_tree) or [Ahnentafeln](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahnentafel)  - are essentially [directed acyclic graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_tree#Graph_theory). But not arbitrary but highly specific ones. I am interested in families of directed acyclic graphs that may serve as realistic models of "real" (human) genealogical "trees". For example with respect to

- "leveledness" (true trees having maximal leveledness),
- average out-degree (while in-degree having to be $2$ - or vice-versa),
- collapsing rate (in the sense of [pedigree collapse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedigree_collapse)),
- extinction rate (probabilty of a node to have no children)

and so on.

Any reference is welcome!

Comment: I've heard lectures on percolation theory being used on trees for similar analysis, for example extinction is governed simply by the critical value. For sub-critical values there are bounds as well, which give you something akin to extinction rates. The literature is vast.

Comment: "Percolation theory" seems to be a good key word I did not know. Thanks. But I wonder how this theory relates to genealogy.

Comment: Google "percolation theory trees", first result I get for example http://www.math.chalmers.se/~steif/perc.pdf see section 5. I didn't go through this particular tutorial, but it looks relevant.

Answer (score 1):

In a paper on [visualization of genealogical graphs](http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~mjmcguff/research/genealogyVis/genealogyVis.pdf) (from 2005) I found this:

> "Interestingly, other than Furnas and Zacks [[5]](http://pdf.aminer.org/000/088/351/multitrees_enriching_and_reusing_hierarchical_structure.pdf), we have been unable to
>   find previous work in the mathematical, graph theory, or graph drawing
>   communities that analyzes the graph theoretic properties of
>   genealogical graphs."

(I wonder whether this is still so.)